# How can I trigger different page animations depending on the last link that was visited?

Tags: animation

I'm trying to put multiple animations on one link (the animation is different depending on which page you are coming from). The site below has a good example of what I am going for. When you click on the work page from the home page, the work page slides in from the right. When you click on the work page from the about page, the work page slides in from the left.

http://howarkitekter.se/work/

I can't seem to figure out how this was done. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

There is different approaches to this, one would be to use JavaScript. In JavaScript, you set up a dictionary that contains the pages titles in your navigation bar as well as a numerical page ID

```
var pages = {
    "Home": 1, "Work": 2, "About": 3, "Contact": 4
}
```

Since usually, a user will start off at the Home page, we will set the default current page to "Home" (this could be adjusted though if needed):

```
//setting the default currentPage to "Home"
var currentPage = "Home";
```

Then you can add an onClick/onTouchEnd Event Listener to every link, which calls a function `changePage(this.innerHTML)`. `this.innerHTML` returns the name of the site clicked, e.g. "Work" when you click on the respective link.

```
function changePage(title) {

    if(pages[title] > pages[currentPage]) {

        //if the ID of the target page is higher than the current page's ID, it is at
        //the right, thus it should animate in from the right side

        transitionPage(title, "fromRight");
    }

    else if(pages[title] < pages[currentPage]) {
        transitionPage(title, "fromLeft");
    }

    //set the currentPage to the page you just transitioned to
    currentPage = title;

}
```

You can replace the "fromRight"/"fromLeft" with Boolean values to make it cleaner, but for readability, I did it like this. In the `transitionPage(targetPage, direction)` function you can specify your code to make the transition happen, but I will omit how to do this here, since you seem to be focused on how to get two different possible actions assigned to the same link. Hope I could help!

---

By the way, the links you have in your navigation technically don't need to be actual HTML anchor elements ( `<a>` ), but for usability and those who have turned off JS in their browser, it is better to have actual, working links included as well, and use JS's `preventDefault` method to prevent the link from loading a new page.